# knitr with latex: how to avoid that dollar symbol $ in comments is substituted with pound symbol £

Tags: r, knitr

I have the following piece of code in a file `example.Rtex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<test, eval=TRUE, echo=TRUE>>=
# $ <- this should be a dollar
a <- list(b=5,c=10)
print(a)
print(a$c)
@
\end{document}
```

Compiling it with

```
echo "library(knitr); knit('example.Rtex')" | R
```

I obtain a file `example.tex`, which still has all dollar symbols in the R code. Next, I run pdflatex on `example.tex`. In the pdf file the dollar symbol in the comment of the R code is changed into a pound symbol `£`. How can I avoid this change?? Why does it happen?

Comment: If `knitr` is writing a dollar sign but LaTeX is producing a pound sign, this sounds like a LaTeX problem rather than a `knitr` problem.  See <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/pounds-and-textsterling-produces-a-dollar-sign>.